# Cant replace color in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I do this simple command

```
 convert zzzzzz     -fill "#702411" -opaque  "#000000"  zzzzzz2
```

in this image but not replace
[image]

What I could do

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve converting from grayscale to rgb with this command

firs rename to jpg and then

```
  convert zzzzzz.png    -colorspace sRGB -type truecolor  zzzzrgb.jpg

  convert zzzzrgb.jpg    -fuzz 20%   -fill "#702411" -opaque  "#000000"  zzzzzz2
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but this single command should be easier... `convert zzzzzz.png  -colorspace RGB -fuzz 20% -fill "#702411" -opaque black result.jpg`